# I wanted to mirror a request based on a query parameter. But Nginx says I can't use mirror inside if directive

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

My Nginx configuration

```
upstream backend_server1 {
    server localhost:3000;  
}

upstream backend {
    server localhost:9000;
}
server {
    server_name localhost;
    listen 8000;

    location / {
        if ($arg_mirrorRequest = true) {
            mirror /mirror;
        }
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    }

    location = /mirror {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://backend_server1;
    }

}
```

In the above configuration Nginx says mirror directive is not allowed in if. How can I mirror the request to backend_server1 only if the query param mirrorRequest is true